# Looping through each column of a dataframe applying a function and save the result as a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I used the following two lines of code to calculate the value of a formula and save the result as a new column in the same dataframe. The formula multiplies the value of each column of a dataframe (df_H) by a value from a dictionary (H) and add up these values (of a single row) and divide them by the sum of all the values of the dictionary and save the result in the same row of the new column (df_H["COI"]).

```
    H = {'G1_H':9.5438, 'G2_H':3.921565, 'G3_H':2.939454}
    df_H['COI'] = pd.Series(((df_H.G1 * H['G1_H']) + (df_H.G3 *H['G3_H']) + ...)/(H['G1_H']+H['G3_H']+...), index=df_H.index)
```

Now I want to re-write the same code so that it loops through all the columns and do the same. The number of columns and the items of a dictionary is changing based on the simulation, however, the number of columns is always equal to the number of dictionary items ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make your approach more general is to do the scalar * column multiplication without explicitly having to name each column.

If you can be sure that your `H` dictionary keys will always exactly match your DataFrame column names, try this:

```
# Multiply each DF column with its corresponding dict value
temp = df_H.transform(lambda x: x * H[x.name])
# Add up transformed rows and divide by the sum of all dict values
df_H['COI'] = temp.sum(axis=1) / sum(H.values())
```

#### Runnable example

```
df_H = pd.DataFrame({'G1_H': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'G2_H': [2, 4, 6, 8], 'G3_H': [-1, 0, 1, 2]})
H = dict(G1_H=1, G2_H=2, G3_H=3)

temp = df_H.transform(lambda x: x * H[x.name])
df_H['COI'] = temp.sum(axis=1) / sum(H.values())

H
{'G1_H': 1, 'G2_H': 2, 'G3_H': 3}

temp
   G1_H  G2_H  G3_H
0     0     4    -3
1     1     8     0
2     2    12     3
3     3    16     6

df_H
   G1_H  G2_H  G3_H       COI
0     0     2    -1  0.166667
1     1     4     0  1.500000
2     2     6     1  2.833333
3     3     8     2  4.166667
```

#### Wordy Explanation

```
temp = df_H.transform(lambda x: x * H[x.name])
```

What `df.transform()` does is process each *column* of `df`, and for each column, return a result with the same length as the input column. So running `df.transform()` always results in a DataFrame with the same shape.

`df.transform()` takes in a function, which in this case is a lambda function (a function with no name defined in-place, as opposed to in advance with `def func_name(arg1):`).

`lambda x: x * H[x.name]` says for each column "`x`" in `df`, multiply it with the dictionary value whose key is `x.name`, which is each column's name. (Remember, the columns in a `DataFrame` are just `Series`, and each column name is accessible through `Series.name`.) This function works because your python dictionary `H` has keys that exactly match the columns in your DF.

```
df_H['COI'] = temp.sum(axis=1) / sum(H.values())
```

By order of operations, this line first adds up the values in each *row* of `temp` (due to `axis=1`), resulting in a Series with only one column in it. (The default dimension of most pandas methods is `axis=0`, which acts on the values in each *column*, which would not work here.)

The result of the summation is then element-wise divided by the sum of all the dictionary values, `sum(H.values())`, which is a scalar. Pandas (really numpy) knows to "broadcast" the scalar across the vector through the division operation, doing what most people would expect the code to do (more about numpy broadcasting here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Comment: Great!. Thank you for your answer. I wonder if you could post the same answer using on-pythonic coding! so I can understand this code.

Comment: You're very welcome! Do you mean the same answer, but *non*-Pythonic? I'll edit in some explanations below my original answer, which should make this code more clear. The pandas approach may look unreadable or confusing at first, but it's definitely worth it :)